# MySQL keeps adding additional user without rights from specific IP

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm running MySQL Server 5.5.29 on Ubuntu Server 13.04

I have a created a user with a wildcard host access `%` and given him various privileges.

However, whenever this user connects from `194.182.245.61`, a new user account is created for that specific IP address with no rights and he is unable to exercise his privileges.

When he connects from other internet connections, such as his home IP, it works just as it should.

Why does this happen and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: MySQL doesn't create accounts automatically. I suspect there is an entry that someone put in for that IP address.  Try `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;`.

Comment: Trust me, it is happening. The same user is recreated using the specific IP as host instead of the wildcard. So the user appears twice in the list. First with a wildcard host (%) and the correct privileges assigned and then again with the specific IP and no privileges assigned.

Comment: I'd file a bug with Oracle then.  It shouldn't happen.

Comment: "the user appears twice in the list" -- what "list" are you referring to?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, the user account list in MySQL Workbench 5.2.41 CE

Comment: Does that list correspond exactly with the values in the mysql.user table? When you remove that invalid account, does the corresponding entry disappear from the mysql.user table?